# Confusion about the use of ng-options.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a following confusion with ng-options. I have build a dropdown from array
located into my controller. Here is my html code:

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <select multiple="multiple" ng-model="first" ng-options="c.name for c in listObj">
    </select>
    <select multiple="multiple" ng-model="second">
    </select>
    <hr/>
    {{first}}
</div>
</div>
```

and this is my JavaScript:

```
function testCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.listObj = [{name: "x", content: [1,2,3]},
                      {name: "y", content: [4,5,6]}];

}
```

And this is working jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zono/rkBUL/10/

When user choose element from left select (with selected CTRL) I want 
the right select to be filled with corespondign content property. 
Eg:

When user select x to the left will be 1,2,3. 
When add y to the left will be 1,2,3,4,5,6.
When deselect x - 4,5,6.

Best regards.

Comment: Why don't you simply add an `ng-options` to your second `<select>` which uses the `ng-model` of your first `<select>`? http://jsfiddle.net/DPBZP/

Comment: This is solution but I want 1,2,3 ant etc to be in separate options.

Comment: Ah, my misunderstanding. Unfortunately, the `ng-options` expression syntax is limited in what it can unpack. If you don't want to rely on a `$watch` as suggested by @package, then you could provide a helper function which unpacks the values in each `content` to display. I've updated the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DPBZP/1/

Comment: Your comment solved me question. Can you post it as answer because I must accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to rely on a `$watch` as suggested by [@package](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991445/package), you can employ a helper function in your controller to unpack each individual value of `content`, for each selected item in `listObj`, into an array for the `ng-options` of your second `<select>`.

```
$scope.contents = function(arr) {
    var values = [];
    if (angular.isDefined(arr)) {
        arr.forEach(function(v) {
            values = values.concat(v.content);
        });
    }
    return values;
};
```

And then:

```
ng-options="c for c in contents(first)"
```

Here's a demonstration [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DPBZP/1).

Answer (score 1):

You have to `$watch` `first`, and when it changes, read content of all selected values into a new array, let's call it `firstContent`. The second `select` would show items from `firstContent`. Here's code from updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkBUL/11/):

```
<select multiple="multiple" ng-model="first" ng-options="c.name for c in listObj">
</select>
<select multiple="multiple" ng-model="second" ng-options="element for element in firstContent">
</select>


$scope.$watch('first', function(value) {
    if (!value) {
        return;
    }
    var firstContent = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        firstContent = firstContent.concat(value[i].content);
    }
    $scope.firstContent = firstContent;
});
```